# XOR encrypting and decryption key

Tags: security, encoding, xor

It is possible to get the key used to encrypt a secuence of characters using xor?

## Example

Lets say that I Have the following string: 1456, so:

- 1 - 49 ascii - 00110001 binary
- 4 - 52 ascii - 00110100 binary
- 5 - 53 ascii - 00110101 binary
- 6 - 54 ascii - 00110110 binary

Key: 100

Then I do the following: 1 ^ 100 (talking in binary: 00110001 ^ 01100100), and get the following result: "UPQR", how do I know that I used the key 100 in xor to encrypt "1456" getting "UPQR" as the result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: XOR does not do much encrypting, its more of an encoding thing...

Comment: @K-ballo ARCFOUR (RC4) algorithm is exactly XOR encryption, and still it's a widely used encryption algorithm used in SSL/TLS as well as in other places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know both the original and the encoded sequence, then for each component it must be that

```
original[i] ^ encoded[i] == key
```

If you don't know the original content, then you would have to try with each possible key and see if the results makes any sense (for some definition of sense).

Comment: Would it be the same if I use & or | instead?

Comment: Sure... just like `1 + 1` is the same than `1 - 1` or `1 * 1`

Comment: I've tryed original[i] & encoded[i], but is not giving me the right key.

Comment: Ok in case you didn't noticed that was sarcasm. They are different operations, why would they give you the same result? And why would you try `l & r` when you need to do `l ^ r`?

Comment: I have to do it using ^, |, &.

Comment: First, if this is homework then there is a tag for it and an important one. Second, `^` is part of the set `{^, |, &}` so once again why would you try `l & r` when you need to do `l ^ r`?

Comment: Oh my bad, caballo. I also believed, that you noticed it was sarcasm.

Answer (score 1):

Note Wikipedia's comment about [XOR cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher)

> By itself, using a constant repeating key, a simple XOR cipher can trivially be broken using [frequency analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis).

Though if the key is the size of the message (and random, and used only once), you have a [one-time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad).  That's just unbreakable, period.  Though it is too cumbersome for most to use.

Comment: It's only a one-time pad if the key is _random_. :)

Comment: @sarnold Why is it that security and encryption always boils down to technicalities?  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a position of code-breaking, then you should definitely check out [Sinkov's Elementary Cryptanlysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0883856220) and [Gaines's Cryptanalysis: A Study of Ciphers and Their Solution](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486200973). Both of these books go into good depth on key recovery for a [Vigenère Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher), which is fairly similar to a sequential application of XOR operations.